# Что лучше выбрать Json.net или DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, json.net

В общем появился вопрос что лучше использовать для десериализации json Json.net или DataContractJsonSerializer  в С#. Мой созданный json типа такой

```
[{
    "Name":"Test1",
    "Author":"Test1",
    "Description": "Тут должно быть описание",
    "Regex":true,
    "Search":"Текст для поиска",
    "Replace":"Текст для замены",
    "Add":"assets/test.txt",
    "Target":"/test.txt",
    "Delete":"/assets/test.txt"
}]
```

Comment: Вкусы у всех разные. Я например ненавижу `DataContractJsonSerializer` и обожаю `Json.net`, для кого то это все наоборот. + задачи, иногда лучше стандартное решение и нет возможности ставить что то от 3-х лиц. Вопрос вкусов!

Comment: На so не приняты вопросы два-в-одном и сто-в-одном, их закрывают как слишком общие. Вынесите вопрос про многострочечные строки в отдельный топик, в этом вопросе лучше вычеркните

Comment: мне важная скорость чтения и выполнения, `DataContractJsonSerializer` мне более прост кажется (написал тестовую читалку), но для чтения выполнения этого файла (это типа разширение) нужно что-то лучшее.

Comment: Вам надо парсить json несколько мегабайт? Вам нужно выжимать миллисекунды (в то время как один SQL-запрос к базе будет занимать сотни миллисекунд)? Вряд ли. Если бы у вас были чёткие требования - вы бы их знали заранее и вписали в вопрос.

Comment: Json.Net обожает по каждому поводу бросать эксцешен или возвращать null :) за что горячо не любим общественностью.. но как верно заметили - о вкусах не спорят.

Comment: Ещё есть [JavaScriptSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2). Всегда пользовался им.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Холиварный вопрос о цвете фломастеров.

Разницы в производительности [особой нет](https://habr.com/en/post/133778/), для большинства практических приложений особо нет разницы по скорости.

Проблемы [могут всплывать](https://habr.com/en/company/mailru/blog/314014/) в средах, где используются разные десериализаторы из-за разночтений в форматах json.

Я люблю Json.Net и привык к её использованию. Кому-то важно не тащить лишние зависимости в проект — и обходится штатным DataContractJsonSerializer.

Но если придётся пересесть по каким-то причинам за DataContractJsonSerializer — проблем  не вижу. Как разработчики мы должны уметь пользоваться инструментами, понадобится перейти на другой — просто потратим время на освоение и всё.

Comment: понял пока -что попробую штатную DataContractJsonSerializer, потом если что-то не сростётся переду на Json.Net. Спасибо